# What is an Amoeboid Word™?

Tags: pattern, word-property

<sub>This is in the spirit of the [What is a Word/Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22what+is+a%22+word+is%3Aquestion) series started by [JLee](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/463) with a special brand of [Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22Phrase%22%20user%3A463%20is%3Aquestion) and [Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22What+is+%22+%22Word%22+-missing+user%3A463+is%3Aquestion) puzzles.</sub>

---

If a word conforms to a special rule, I like to call it an ***Amoeboid Word™***.
Find the rule that decides whether a word is an *Amoeboid Word™* or not, and why they are called so.

| Amoeboid Word™ | Non-Amoeboid Word™ |
| --- | --- |
| BALLOONED | INFLATED |
| HEAVIER | BULKIER |
| FURRINESS | HAIRINESS |
| ALLIED | AFFILIATED |
| LOUNGE | SETTEE |
| SOURNESS | ACRIDNESS |
| FRIEND | COMPANION |
| STAINED | BLEMISHED |
| SWEATY | CLAMMY |
| THEOREM | POSTULATE |

---

**CSV Version:**

```
Amoeboid Word™,Non-Amoeboid Word™
BALLOONED,INFLATED
HEAVIER,BULKIER
FURRINESS,HAIRINESS
ALLIED,AFFILIATED
LOUNGE,SETTEE
SOURNESS,ACRIDNESS
FRIEND,COMPANION
STAINED,BLEMISHED
SWEATY,CLAMMY
THEOREM,POSTULATE
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

A word is Amoeboid if

> The odd letters and even letters both spell out words.

It is called Amoeboid because

> <s>Amoebae are unicellular organisms that can combine to form multinucleate organisms?</s>
>  As per El-Guest, an amoeba can split into two fully viable amoebae.

Demonstration:

> ```
>  BALLOONED      ->   BLOND     &    ALOE
>  HEAVIER        ->   HAIR      &    EVE
>  FURRINESS      ->   FRIES     &    URNS
>  ALLIED         ->   ALE       &    LID
>  LOUNGE         ->   LUG       &    ONE
>  SOURNESS       ->   SUNS      &    ORES
>  FRIEND         ->   FIN       &    RED
>  STAINED        ->   SAND      &    TIE
>  SWEATY         ->   SET       &    WAY
>  THEOREM        ->   TERM      &    HOE
> ```

Comment: They rot13(pfcyvg vagb gjb shyyl ivnoyr nzbronr)

Comment: @El-Guest Thank you! I should have researched that part a bit more.

Comment: Any formatting inside spoiler tags is finicky, at best. I find the easiest one to use is just a `<pre> </pre>` block, each row prefixed with the spoiler tag `>!`.

Comment: So the word `Amoeboid` itself is not an Amoeboid Word™?